# Remove unmatched criteria records from Eloquent collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have some problems with Eloquent Eager Loading. I have added `whereHas` to remove the blog don't meet the comment criteria but the comment stills return empty array. My intention is to completely remove it from the json record.

How can I completely remove the json data chain that does not meet my condition?

My current code:

```php
User::select("id", "name", "email")
    ->with(['blog', 'blog.author', 'blog.comments' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('comment', 'John is here');
    }, 'blog.comments.owner'])
    ->whereHas('blog.comments', function ($query) {
        $query->where('comment', 'John is Here');
    })
    ->get();
```

My current json output is:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email": "john.smith@hotmail.com",
    "blog": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-04-09T18:08:06.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-04-09T10:33:03.000000Z",
            "title": "First Blog",
            "description": "Awesome",
            "users_id": 1,
            "cover": null,
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "John Smith",
                "email": "john.smith@hotmail.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                "role": 0
            },
            "comments": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "comment": "John is here",
                    "blog_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "owner": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "John Smith",
                        "email": "john.smith@hotmail.com",
                        "email_verified_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                        "role": 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "created_at": "2021-04-12T07:41:43.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-04-12T08:01:18.000000Z",
            "title": "Second Blog",
            "description": "Awesome",
            "users_id": 1,
            "cover": "images/json_1618213303.png",
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "John Smith",
                "email": "john.smith@hotmail.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                "role": 0
            },
            "comments": []
        }
    ]
}
```

My expected output would be:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email": "john.smith@hotmail.com",
    "blog": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-04-09T18:08:06.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-04-09T10:33:03.000000Z",
            "title": "First Blog",
            "description": "Awesome",
            "users_id": 1,
            "cover": null,
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "John Smith",
                "email": "john.smith@hotmail.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                "role": 0
            },
            "comments": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "comment": "John is here",
                    "blog_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "owner": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "John Smith",
                        "email": "john.smith@hotmail.com",
                        "email_verified_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
                        "role": 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` and share the SQL that is running ?

Comment: select `id`, `name`, `email` from `users` where exists (select * from `blogs` where `users`.`id` = `blogs`.`users_id` and exists (select * from `comments` where `blogs`.`id` = `comments`.`blog_id` and `comment` = ?))

Comment: I though it will execute inner join

Comment: This is a little bit out of my league, I mean, it is too much for me to help you, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
User::select("id", "name", "email")
    ->with([
        'blog' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
                $query->where('comment', 'John is Here');
            });
        }, 
        'blog.comments' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('comment', 'John is here');
        },
        'blog.author',  
        'blog.comments.owner'])
    ->get();
```

You should be applying the constraint on `blog` eager loading as well. Your query only filters `comments` of a `blog`

Comment: I have a question for the eloquent model, how can I construct a join query incorporate with the eloquent model but the output must return me as collection. I have attempted to use something like "User::join("user_role","id","=","user.role_id")" but this can lead another problem when someone decide to change table name, it can directly crash entire code.

Comment: I would suggest accessing the related record like so `$user->roles`, but you first have to define the many-to-many `roles` relationship between `User` model and `Role`.